# Mosquitto Universal Subscriber

Tags: eclipse, mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I need to subscribe to all the topics of the broker as the superuser. I have tried adding "/" as the topic, but it didn't work. Please let me know how to subscribe every topic without adding separate topic subscriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after referring the mosquitto man pages. You need to just add # as the wild card to the topic.

http://mosquitto.org/man/mqtt-7.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you figured out how to subscribe to wildcard (by subscribing to '#'). If you are looking for more in-depth information about wildcards and topic best practices, you might find this blog post useful: http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices/